# ASP.NET MVC : Интегрированная проверка безопасности ввода паролей от Google рекомендует изменить пароль при входе

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, md5, password, password-hash

При кодировании (MD5) пароля из текстбокса и его последующей проверки из базы данных (тоже в виде хэша) Google Chrome дает рекомендацию изменить пароль, так как он был раскрыт в ходе выполнения, при этом я никогда не оперирую с паролем в чистом виде. Вот моя функция, которая осуществляет вход :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
void Login()
    {
        List<Mail> users = new MailContext().Mails.ToList();
        Mail m = users.Where(x => x.Nickname == tbUsername.Text.Trim(' ')).Where(x => x.Pwd == CalculateMD5Hash(tbPassword.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (m != default(Mail)) { userAcc.Id = m.Id; userAcc.Nickname = m.Nickname; userAcc.Email = m.Email; userAcc.Pwd = "NO_PERMISSION"; ShowTools(); }
        else
        {
            btnRedeemCode.Text = "Fail";
            btnRedeemCode.CssClass = "buttonRed";
            btnRedeemCode.ToolTip = "User not found or credentials do not match";
        }
    }
```

Возможно ли избежать этого сообщения при сверке пароля из базы?